Getting a count dynamically for Customers first time orders and also orders lost after last order date + 4 months, per year and month
I am trying to dynamically get a count at a per month basis per customer and type. Where two of the counts are the first time we got an order based on the program and the other two are programs/customers we lost based on their last order date and 4 or 5 months have passed since.
The new customers per month is correct but the lost customers is not in both queries I have created.
There is a few issues with the data, one the invoicing data that I am using doesn't have a unique identifier so to create one I am using concat with First name, Last name, DOB and Type of program.
I.E  FirstLast2024-09-12Type
Second issue I cant get around is the count for lost customers, I have been trying multiple ways and landed on the below two queries and have got different results for lost customers with each query. The first orders in my data set is 2021-01 so there should be no lost customers for those first months as no ones last order could be before 2021-01. I am hoping it is something small but even after taking a few days break from it I can't wrap my head around it.. First Query:
with dates as (
      select convert(date, '2019-01-01') as dt
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dt)
      from dates
      where dt < getdate()
     )
Select  left(dt,7) as [date],count(*) as [new_customers], sum(case when right(b.[id],3) = 'IPP' and left(b.[1st_order],7) = left(dt,7) then 1 else 0 end) as [new_IPP_customers], 
sum(case when right(b.[id],3) = 'MAP' and left(b.[1st_order],7) = left(dt,7) then 1 else 0 end) as [new_MAP_customers],
sum(case when right(b.[id],3) = 'IPP' and datediff(m,dt,b.[Last]) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Lost_IPP_customers],
sum(case when right(b.[id],3) = 'MAP' and datediff(m,dt,b.[Last]) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Lost_MAP_customers]
from dates
Left Join(
Select CONCAT(a.[First Name],a.[Last Name],a.[DOB],a.Solution) as [id], min(dos) as [1st_order],max(llast) as [last]
FROM [MYTABLE] a
Left Join(
Select CONCAT([First Name],[Last Name],[DOB],Solution) as [id], dateadd(m,4,max(dos)) as [llast]
FROM [MYTABLE] a
Group by CONCAT([First Name],[Last Name],[DOB],[Solution])) b on b.id = CONCAT(a.[First Name],a.[Last Name],a.[DOB],a.Solution)
Group by CONCAT(a.[First Name],a.[Last Name],a.[DOB],a.Solution)) b on left(b.[1st_order],7) = left(dt,7)
where b.id is not null
Group by left(dt,7)
order by left(dt,7)


Results:
1st query results
Second query: just tried different ways to join etc..
with dates as (
      select convert(date, '2019-01-01') as dt
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dt)
      from dates
      where dt < getdate()
     )
Select  left(dt,7) as [date],count(*) as [new_customers], sum(case when right(b.[id],3) = 'IPP' and left(b.[1st_order],7) = left(dt,7) then 1 else 0 end) as [new_IPP_customers], 
sum(case when right(b.[id],3) = 'MAP' and left(b.[1st_order],7) = left(dt,7) then 1 else 0 end) as [new_MAP_customers],

sum(case when right(c.[id],3) = 'IPP' and datediff(m,dt,c.[Last_order]) > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as [Lost_IPP_customers],
sum(case when right(c.[id],3) = 'MAP' and datediff(m,dt,c.[Last_order]) > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as [Lost_MAP_customers]
from dates
Left Join(
Select a.[id],  min(dos) as [1st_order]
From
(Select *,CONCAT([First Name],[Last Name],[DOB],Solution) as [id]
FROM [MYTABLE) a
Group by a.[id]) b on left(b.[1st_order],7) = left(dt,7) 
Left Join(
Select a.[id],  max(dos) [Last_order]
From
(Select *,CONCAT([First Name],[Last Name],[DOB],Solution) as [id]
FROM [MYTABLE]) a
Group by a.[id]) c on b.[id] = c.id 
where c.id is not null
Group by left(dt,7)
order by left(dt,7)

Results:
2nd Query Results
Note: Count * was just to make sure the new customers added up for visual purposes.
Here is example of how the data set looks before joining to a calendar table and sum cases:
First and Last orders
The new customers per month is correct but the lost customers is not in both queries I have created.
EDIT: I failed to notice the first query sum counts for first and lost are the same count as each other, the second query is what i started with and I tried to make it simpler and created the first query as the second query wasn't populating the lost customers correctly.
Here is example data from "mytable" I blocked off parts of the data for privacy.. I also added two tables to the post of example data and What I am trying to accomplish with that data provided.
MYtable_Data
Example data:



First Name
Last Name
DOB
Member Number
DOS
Medication
Solution
Day Supply
Insurance
Amount Due
Payment Status
Invoice #
Inv# Date




Name
Fake
1968-01-11
NULL
2023-10-26
Ocrevus
MAP
180
0.00
9890.40
PAID
111
2023-11-09


Name
Fake
1968-01-11
NULL
2022-10-31
Ocrevus
MAP
180
0.00
8723.9825
PAID
222
2022-11-18


Name
Fake
1968-01-11
NULL
2023-04-29
Ocrevus
MAP
180
0.00
9890.40
PAID
333
2023-05-12


Name1
Fake1
1998-03-22
NULL
2022-06-02
Novolog Flextouch
IPP
90
0.00
541.08
PAID
123456
2022-06-22


Name1
Fake1
1998-03-22
NULL
2021-06-04
Novolog
IPP
90
0.00
541.62
PAID
123
2021-07-20


Name1
Fake1
1998-03-22
NULL
2021-06-04
Basaglar
IPP
90
0.00
551.76
PAID
123
2021-07-20


Name1
Fake1
1998-03-22
NULL
2022-03-08
Lantus Solostar Pens
IPP
90
0.00
665.97
PAID
12368
2022-04-20


Name2
Fake2
1982-11-16
NULL
2022-09-29
Creon
MAP
90
0.00
1235.07
PAID
3698
2022-11-04


Name2
Fake2
1982-11-16
NULL
2023-10-10
Creon
IPP
100
0.00
1874.56
PAID
516
2023-10-27


Name2
Fake2
1982-11-16
NULL
2023-06-26
Creon
MAP
90
0.00
1238.00
PAID
44
2023-08-07



Using the example data above the output should look like below with the lost customer count being 4 months after the DOS (but the real results would have every year and month in order from x number of years ago to today's month, I shortened the results for viewing purposes.



date
new_IPP_customers
new_MAP_customers
Lost_IPP_customers
Lost_MAP_customers




2021-06
1
0
0
0


2022-09
0
1
0
0


2022-10
0
1
0
1


2023-10
1
0
0
1


2024-02
0
0
1
1




We will need example data from MYTABLE

And please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. If you want to support sample data please do so as DDL and DML statements, and supply expected results in a Markdown Table.

And don't provide data in screenshots, does one suppose to type it all in just to test run something? Think about helping others help you. Also, feel free to remove the goo that isn't needed, for example program type, if it's not relevant to the main problem. A minimal example goes a long way

Please format your code properly.  If code is unreadable, most likely people are just going to skip it.

Something like this can be a good start perhaps:
--Data
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'Name', N'Fake', N'1968-01-11', NULL, N'2023-10-26', N'Ocrevus', N'MAP', 180, 0.00, 9890.40, N'PAID', 111, N'2023-11-09')
    ,   (N'Name', N'Fake', N'1968-01-11', NULL, N'2022-10-31', N'Ocrevus', N'MAP', 180, 0.00, 8723.9825, N'PAID', 222, N'2022-11-18')
    ,   (N'Name', N'Fake', N'1968-01-11', NULL, N'2023-04-29', N'Ocrevus', N'MAP', 180, 0.00, 9890.40, N'PAID', 333, N'2023-05-12')
    ,   (N'Name1', N'Fake1', N'1998-03-22', NULL, N'2022-06-02', N'Novolog Flextouch', N'IPP', 90, 0.00, 541.08, N'PAID', 123456, N'2022-06-22')
    ,   (N'Name1', N'Fake1', N'1998-03-22', NULL, N'2021-06-04', N'Novolog', N'IPP', 90, 0.00, 541.62, N'PAID', 123, N'2021-07-20')
    ,   (N'Name1', N'Fake1', N'1998-03-22', NULL, N'2021-06-04', N'Basaglar', N'IPP', 90, 0.00, 551.76, N'PAID', 123, N'2021-07-20')
    ,   (N'Name1', N'Fake1', N'1998-03-22', NULL, N'2022-03-08', N'Lantus Solostar Pens', N'IPP', 90, 0.00, 665.97, N'PAID', 12368, N'2022-04-20')
    ,   (N'Name2', N'Fake2', N'1982-11-16', NULL, N'2022-09-29', N'Creon', N'MAP', 90, 0.00, 1235.07, N'PAID', 3698, N'2022-11-04')
    ,   (N'Name2', N'Fake2', N'1982-11-16', NULL, N'2023-10-10', N'Creon', N'IPP', 100, 0.00, 1874.56, N'PAID', 516, N'2023-10-27')
    ,   (N'Name2', N'Fake2', N'1982-11-16', NULL, N'2023-06-26', N'Creon', N'MAP', 90, 0.00, 1238.00, N'PAID', 44, N'2023-08-07')
) t ([First Name],[Last Name],DOB,[Member Number],DOS,Medication,Solution,[Day Supply],Insurance,[Amount Due],[Payment Status],[Invoice #],[Inv# Date])

-- Code
;WITH dates AS (
      SELECT    CONVERT(date, '2019-01-01') AS dt
      UNION ALL
      SELECT    dateadd(month, 1, dt)
      FROM  dates
      WHERE dt < getdate()
     )
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), dt, 112)
,   ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN solution = 'IPP' THEN x.gained END), 0) AS IPPGained
,   ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN solution = 'IPP' THEN x.lost END), 0) AS IPPLost
,   ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN solution = 'MAP' THEN x.gained END), 0) AS MAPGained
,   ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN solution = 'MAP' THEN x.lost END), 0) AS MAPLost
FROM    dates d
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  sa.*
    FROM    (
        SELECT  CASE WHEN lag(dos) OVER(partition BY CONCAT([First Name], [Last Name], DOB, Solution) ORDER BY DOS) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS first
        ,   CASE WHEN LEAD(dos) OVER(partition BY CONCAT([First Name], [Last Name], DOB, Solution) ORDER BY DOS) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS last
        ,   *
        FROM    #data d
    ) d
    CROSS apply (
        SELECT  solution, first AS gained, 0 AS lost, DOS
        WHERE   first = 1
    UNION ALL
        SELECT  solution, 0, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, 4, Dos)
        WHERE   last = 1
    ) sa
    ) x
    ON  EOMONTH(x.DOS) = EOMONTH(d.dt)
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), dt, 112)

The core of the idea is to create two flags, first and last order.
I use LAG/LEAD window function to do so, and PARTITION BY the identifiers like First, last, Solution to distinguish the different groups of customers.
Now, to simplify the gain/losses, I create two rows:

First row, which has 1 gained and 0 loss, DOS as order date
Last row, which has 0 gained, 1 loss and DOS 4 months into the future

This simplifies our logic later.
Finally, i join back on the dates CTE and use conditional aggregation (CASE WHEN ...) to generate the tabulated format you're looking for.
For the date join, i use EOMONTH to simplify the date handling, this function returns the last date of the month ie. a single date. Feel free to use something else, i wasn't going for the most performant solution, but rather to demonstrate main concept.

Wow thanks! I didn't even consider that Lead and Lag would work for something like this. I was too focused on the min and max. Is it possible to change the 4 months into the future to be more dynamic, for instance instead of just 4 months in the future the logic they've been using to count if someone was a lost customer was DOS + [day supply]. If its been more than 2 months from that date then they should be considered lost. Some orders are  30-90 days. So based off what type is (the ID) we made we want to only mark them as lost if its been more than 60 days or 2 months from DOS + day supply.

Yeah, it sounds like you just need to change the dateadd to the logic you wrote down. Something like: DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEADD(DAYS, <day supply value>, DOS))
